# How to disable header checking in apache?

Tags: apache-2.4

I need to bypass a malformed header request that has a header field `Content type` (note the space, unlike `Content-Type`) and value `form-data` and allow the request to be performed, but currently it returns `400 bad request`.

I've already tried the following to unset it but since the malformed request contains `space`in header field-name, it doesn't works.

```
RequestHeader unset Content type
RequestHeader unset "Content type"
RequestHeader unset 'Content type'
RequestHeader set Content-Type "multipart/form-data"
```

I also disabled `mod_headers` but it still sends `400 response`.

Any idea I can disable checking or allow the header with `space` in the field-name?

PS. I can't correct the malformed request on the client/app.

Comment: I understand that [whitespace is not allowed in field name](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.4), but I need to because I have no control over the client to correct the request. And strangely, this was working until few weeks ago and for some reason not anymore.

Comment: which version are you using? 2.4.25 brought a more strict behaviour regarding http requests. You can check with directive HttpProtocolOptions how to adjust this behaviour if necessary. Note that allowing clients do thing "their wrong way" is usually the worst case scenario. You can also append a parameter called "early" for early modification of headers before the request is processed, but it is not recommended either.

Comment: I get the 400 from both server `2.4.18 (ubuntu)` and my machine `2.4.25 (unix)`. I've used `early` too - getting same `400` back. I'll check `HttpProtocolOptions` now, thanks.